# Lógica para multiples inserciones de datos en la BD desde Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy intentando insertar multiples registros en la BD pero necesito aplicar una lógica, ya que...

la consulta se puede hacer de esta forma:

```php
Action::create(['module_id' => 1, 'name' => 'ver', 'reference' => 'index', 'route' => 'dashboard.index']);
Action::create(['module_id' => 1, 'name' => 'crear', 'reference' => 'create', 'route' => 'dashboard.create']);
Action::create(['module_id' => 1, 'name' => 'guardar', 'reference' => 'guardar', 'route' => 'dashboard.store']);
Action::create(['module_id' => 1, 'name' => 'eliminar', 'reference' => 'destroy', 'route' => 'dashboard.destroy']);
Action::create(['module_id' => 1, 'name' => 'actualizar', 'reference' => 'update', 'route' => 'dashboard.update']);

// clientes
Action::create(['module_id' => 2, 'name' => 'ver', 'reference' => 'index', 'route' => 'clientes.index']);
$create = Action::create(['module_id' => 2, 'name' => 'crear', 'reference' => 'create', 'route' => 'clientes.create']);
Action::create(['module_id' => 2, 'name' => 'guardar', 'reference' => 'store', 'route' => 'clientes.store','parent' => $create->id]);
$create = Action::create(['module_id' => 2, 'name' => 'editar', 'reference' => 'edit', 'route' => 'clientes.edit']);
Action::create(['module_id' => 2, 'name' => 'eliminar', 'reference' => 'destroy', 'route' => 'clientes.destroy']);
Action::create(['module_id' => 2, 'name' => 'actualizar', 'reference' => 'update', 'route' => 'clientes.update','parent' => $create->id]);
```

Pero la idea es hacerlo iterativo, es decir con un **bucle foreach**
El campo module_id hace referencia al id de la tabla modulos, y la ruta se debe crear concatenando el nombre del modulo y el campo 'reference'

Comment: Bueno te explico un poco la logica que pensé yo... supuse en crear una matriz llamada "names" donde se almacene 'guardar, editar, etc..' como es ve en el eloquent create del modelo action alli, esos datos que cambian, almacenarlos en una matriz y luego insertarlos iterando por la longitud de modulos existente

Comment: son 34 modulos existentes y la idea era iterar sobre una matriz que contenga todos los modulos, obtener el id de cada uno y agregarlos en el campo 'module_id'

Comment: de hecho en la ultima linea de la pregunta explico lo que necesito

Comment: No veo ningún patrón como para meter todo en un foreach. De donde sacas los nombres y las referencias?  Como sabes cual acción tiene parent y cual no?

Comment: Hola IGP, habra un chat donde me pueda comunicar contigo? hay ciertos detalles tanto de este problema como otro que estoy intentando hacer en JS.

Comment: de js no creo poder ayudarte. Pero bueno aquí está un link a un chat de stackoverflow. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128091/discusion-abdiel-igp